# how to cut a 3X3 array from a given grid with out indexOutOfBound exception

Tags: java, arrays

im stuck building a function that takes a given 2d-char array and a Point inside of it, that takes the given point coordinate and builds a new 2d-char array that surrounds the point.

for example if the original grid is:

a b c d e
 z h a f c
 g y z q x
 r z x s a
 k j h z z

the answer of point (0,0) should be:
 ? ? ?
 ? a b
 ? z h

the answer of point(2,2) should be:
h a f
y z q
z x s

```
public int numOfColors(Point p) {
    char [][] neighbors = new char[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++){                              

        for(int j = 0; j < neighbors.length; j++){
            neighbors[i][j]='?';
        }
    }

    int pX = p.getX(), pY = p.getY();
    for(int i = pX - 1; (i < map.length) && (i < pX + 1) ; i++){                       //runs on the original map and copy to neighbors
        for (int j = pY - 1; (j < map.length) && (j < pY + 1); j++){
            neighbors[i-pX+1][j-pY+1]=map[i][j];
            }
        }


    for(int k = 0; k < neighbors.length; k++){                                  //runs on the neighbors array. if a point is an edge point.copy the given point color to the '?' cell 
        for(int l = 0; l < neighbors.length; l++){
            if(neighbors[k][l]=='?') 
                neighbors[k][l]= map[pX][pY];
        }
    }
```

I've been sitting on this all day, the correct answer will be rewarded with a beer

Comment: Have you tried using an if statement to see if i/j are valid coordinates for your arrays?

Comment: There is a indexOutOfBounds because you don't check the bounds of map... what if map calls for [-1][-1]?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to begin from a helper method

```
private char getValue(int x, int y) {
  if (x < 0 || x >= xSize || y < 0 || y >= ySize) {
    return '?';
  }

  return neighbors[x][y]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void extract(char [][] arr, int row, int col){
    char [][] ex = new char [3][3];

    int rc = 0;
    int cc = 0;
    for(int i=row-1; i<row+2; i++){
        for(int j=col-1; j<col+2; j++){
            if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= arr.length || j >= arr[i].length){
                ex[rc][cc] = '?';
            }  else {
                ex[rc][cc] = arr[i][j];
            }
            cc++;
        }
        rc++;
        cc = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            System.out.print (ex[i][j] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Row, Col is Point(x,y).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the out of bounds exception is happened when using this bit of code, since you aren't checking if px - 1 is -1 and the same for py:

```
   for(int i = px - 1; (i < map.length) && (i < px + 1) ; i++){                               //runs on the original map and copy to neighbors
    for (int j = py - 1; (j < map.length) && (j < py + 1); j++){
        neighbors[i-pX+1][j-pY+1]=map[i][j];
        }
    }
```

You could change it to something like this:

```
int x1 = Math.max(p.getX() - 1, 0);
int x2 = Math.min(p.getX() + 1, map.length);
int y1 = Math.max(p.getY() - 1, 0);
int y2 = Math.min(p.getY() + 1, map[0].length);
int xCount = 0;
int yCount = 0;
```

and then:

```
 for(int i = x1; i < x2; i++) {                               //runs on the original map and copy to neighbors
     for (int j = y1; j < y2; j++) {
         neighbors[xCount][yCount++]=map[i][j];
     }
    yCount = 0;
    xCount++;
 }
```

Comment: dbbrown93m thank you very much for the idea,
it's still not working but i think im on the right direction now